# How does line length scale with axes?

Tags: geometry

Today I learned that there is no "simple" formula for the [circumference of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference). This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nW3nJhBHL0) explores some approximations.

When you scale a shape along some axis by some factor $k$, the area will also scale by $k$. A line directed along that axis would also scale by $k$ but a perpendicular line will not scale at all, and an arbitrary line segment will scale by a factor determined by its projection onto the axis -- i.e. something to do with cosines and/or square roots.

That's as far as I got. Is there a general formula for the how the length of an arbitrary line scales as its axes scale?

Comment: The determinant can be interpreted as a signed area and scaling the axes is a linear transformation.

Comment: One can make a general formula, but it would depend upon the both slope of the line segment and the scaling parameters—and at that point it's just as easy to calculate the new endpoints and compute the length directly.